# What should I do for a reliable checkout flow with Paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

A listener on my website 'listens' for successful purchases made via Paypal. Data retrieved by the listener includes a post variable that I can set before initiating the purchase. This is possible with Paypal's IPN(Instant Payment Notification). I am trying to get the IPN to recognize the users account on my website upon purchase. Every account on my website has a unique user ID number.

I have tried passing the accounts unique ID through Paypal's "Custom" variable so the IPN can listen for that. Though I think this is a bad idea because then people can purchase things for another account if they passed their unique ID. Though this is a guaranteed purchase handler, hackers can take advantage of this with social engineering.

I see that some people instead pass the [session_id with php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php), but this isn't safe because the listener would have no way of recognizing the user's website account if the session_id were to disappear. I also see that people will pass a cookie tied to the user's unique account. I don't think this is a good idea because the cookie could be cleared.

It is to my impression that I can not send a refund or cancel a purchase if the user's account could not be identified(Without doing it manually). What checkout flow should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a local invoice record in your system, and this invoice would get a customer ID associated with it.

Then you can use the INVOICE parameter to pass the invoice ID to PayPal, and that would come back in IPN where you can then lookup the customer ID based on that invoice ID.